# A topology induced by $d$ is finer than finite complement topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, Let $\mathscr T$ be a topology induced by $d$, and let $\mathscr U$ be the finite complement topology on $X$. Prove that $\mathscr T$ is finer than $\mathscr U$.

**My attempt:-**

Let $A\in \mathscr U$, then $X \setminus A$ is finite. I am able to deduce upto this.  How do I prove that $A$ is open with respect to $d$? Please help me. I tried like this. Let $x \in A$. How do I choose open ball $B(x;r)\subset A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{p_1,\ldots,p_r\}=X\setminus A$ and define $r=\min\bigl\{d(x,p_j)\,|\,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,r\}\bigr\}$ (unless $X\setminus A$ is empty, in which case $r$ can be any positive number). Then $B(x;r)\subset A$.

Comment: $X\A=\phi \implies A=X$. Why did you point out this trivial case?Is it required?

Comment: Even trivial cases are cases.

Answer (score 1):

In a metric space, a point is closed, thus the complement $A$ of a finite subset is open.

Comment: but closed sets are not defined in the chapter.

Answer (score 1):

The set $X\setminus A$ is finite, thus it is closed w.r.t the metric $d$. In the language of sequences, pick any convergent sequence in the finite set. You will find the sequence is eventually constant, thus the set is closed.

Comment: but closed sets are not defined in the chapter.

Comment: @Mathgeek For that case CarlosSantos gives an explicit answer.

Comment: You forgot the possibility $A=\varnothing$.

Comment: @drhab for that case the statement is vacuously true, no problem there :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be closed in $\mathscr U$ then $F$ is the whole set or it is a finite set.

These sets are always closed in a metrizable space.

Comment: but closed sets are not defined in the chapter.

Comment: A set is closed if it is the complement of an open set. I think you should go for the answer of @José. He only uses open sets.